# Matplotlib patches - position rectangle flush with figure frame

Tags: python, matplotlib, patch

I have created a couple of rectangles to add to a figure, like so:

```
rectangle1 = patches.Rectangle((-.5,.3), 1, .9, ec=None, fc=(0,0,0,.7), zorder=0, clip_on=False, in_layout=False)
```

I want this rectangle to be flush with both the left vertical frame spine/edge (which it is) and also the top and bottom frame edges (which it is not). Instead, as I increase the size of the rectangle beyond either the first or final `ytick`, the vertical dimension of the entire figure frame increases in size, like there is some kind of invisible margin blocking the rectangle from reaching the top and bottom edge. I thought setting both `clip_on` and `in_layout` to False would fix this, but no such luck.

What am I missing? Thanks

Image added: In the left-hand subplot, what happens to the figure frame if I increase the size of the rectangle beyond the uppermost ytick. In the right-hand subplot, the maximum size of the rectangle before it starts expanding the figure frame.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [set_ylim](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_ylim.html) to set the limits on y axis.

It is applied to an axis object. If you don't have axes objects in your code, you can find them using [get_axes](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html); `get_axes` one of `figure`'s methods.

So the code to set the y limits to all axes on your figure could be something like

```
for ax_ in gcf().get_axes():
  ax_.set_ylim(0, 1.2)
```

Comment: Excellent, that fixed it. Thank you Yulia.